# Getting __VA_OPT__ to be recognized by Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, visual-studio-2022, variadic-macros

Tried to set `/std:c++20` or `/std:c++latest` along `/Zc:preprocessor` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=msvc-170) but Visual Studio refuses to recognize `__VA_OPT__` in the following snippet:

```
#define _sdk_log(fmt, ...) \
    printf(fmt __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Since the keyword isn't recognized, every place this macro is used errors like this:

> Error C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '**VA_OPT**'

**Question:**

How can I get Visual Studio to recognize `__VA_OPT__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `__VA_OPT__` support in MSVC is broken in some versions of Visual Studio.
I tested this with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, version 17.8.3.

Because `__VA_OPT__` is a C++20 feature you will need to specify `std:c++20` or later, but on my system that does not help.
However if you use `/Zc:preprocessor` it does have *some* effect.
The following code will work as in most other compilers:

```
#define _sdk_log(fmt, ...) \
    printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Now your code will compile the same in MSVC, gcc and Clang.
The `##` will eat any leading comma in most compilers, the above compiler switch brings MSVC in line with everyone else.

This is documented by MS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=msvc-170#comma-elision-in-variadic-macros

Comment: *"does have some effect"* Wdym? `/Zc:preprocessor` makes `__VA_OPT__` work correctly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, in which version of MSVC does that hold? Because it is broken in my fully up-to-date compiler.

Comment: Apparently you need both `/Zc:preprocessor` and `/std:c++latest` (or `/std:c++20`) for `__VA_OPT__`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, nope I tried that and it is very much borken, both with c++20 and c++latest.

Comment: Works for me here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/71qMrMzbG

Comment: Interesting, let me see if these is some update that can be done.